# Unable to print multiple form input Data in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React and trying to print values of the Input on submit button. I declared an empty state and stored the input value in it. When trying to show a single input data, I am not getting any error. Now, I was trying to store it in an array and display via a Results component through Map method.

Error:

```
TypeError: item.map is not a function
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Result from './Result';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';


export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
      this.state={
        items:'',
        addedItems:[]
      }
      this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

     handleChange(e){
       this.setState({
         items:e.target.value
       })
     }

     handleSubmit(e){
      this.setState({
        addedItems:this.state.items
      })
     }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
          <Navbar/>
          <Jumbotron>
          <p>
            Enter the things you would like to buy.
          </p>
        </Jumbotron>

        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Control value={this.state.items} onChange={this.handleChange}type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </Form.Group>
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>

        </Form>
        <Result item={this.state.addedItems} />       
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Result.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup'

export default function Result(props) {
    const {item}=props;
    //let show=item.map(item=>item);
  let itemShow=item.map(i=>{
      return <li>{i}</li>
  })  

    return (
        <div>
            <ListGroup>
               {itemShow}
            </ListGroup>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding condition like, ```item && item.map(i => { ... })```??

Comment: This code appears to change `addedItems` to a string: `this.setState({ addedItems: this.state.items })`. Is this intended?

Comment: It still gives the same error irrespective of me keeping it as a string, an array or an obj.

Comment: In the ```Result``` function, can you add ```console.log(item)```  before the map function?

Comment: It just prints the 1st input value and then gives the same error.